# TypeError: json is not iterable

Tags: javascript, java, electron

The Error

```
C:\Development\AlphaLauncher-Recode\app\assets\js\loggerutil.js:29 [Launcher] TypeError: json is not iterable
    at DistroIndex._resolveInstances (C:\Development\AlphaLauncher-Recode\app\assets\js\distromanager.js:260)
    at Function.fromJSON (C:\Development\AlphaLauncher-Recode\app\assets\js\distromanager.js:253)
    at Request._callback (C:\Development\AlphaLauncher-Recode\app\assets\js\distromanager.js:327)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Development\AlphaLauncher-Recode\node_modules\request\request.js:185)
    at Request.emit (events.js:203)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Development\AlphaLauncher-Recode\node_modules\request\request.js:1161)
    at Request.emit (events.js:203)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Development\AlphaLauncher-Recode\node_modules\request\request.js:1083)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208)
```

This is the error I get when I try to run the launcher that I've made. The source code is not made public yet on my github, however, what I need it to do is grab the distribution index from my dropbox to allow the launcher to load in the instance for the launcher to run.

The code for the request and catch.

```
exports.DistroIndex;

exports.Types = {
    Library: 'Library',
    ForgeHosted: 'ForgeHosted',
    Forge: 'Forge',
    ForgeMod: 'ForgeMod',
    File: 'File',
    VersionManifest: 'VersionManifest'
}

let data = null;

exports.pullRemote = async function(distroURL) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let opts = {
            url: distroURL,
            timeout: 10000
        }
        request(opts, (error, _resp, body) => {
            if(!error) {
                try {
                    data = DistroIndex.fromJSON(JSON.parse(body));
                    resolve(data);
                } 
                catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            }
            else {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

exports.getDistribution = function() {
    return data;
}
```

I've been playing around with it for a while, any idea on how to fix this? I've been trying but maybe with a fresh pair of eyes, we can fix the problem together.

This is a minecraft launcher by the way with automatic updates and modded jar downloads.

Comment: Don't parse it?

Comment: The error is coming from `DistroIndex.fromJSON`. My guess is that `body` is expected to be an array but it's an object in this context or you're not supposed to parse it in advance. Can we see the code of DistroIndex?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KHUF8Txg < if you need the distromanager.js and the distro file I can give it you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
_resolveInstances(json) {
    const arr = [];
    for(let s of json) {
        arr.push(Instance.fromJSON(s));
    }
    this.instances = arr;
}
```

Error from here, `for(let s of json)` JSON object can't be iterable.
You can use like this to read JSON object values per key.

```
for(const key in json) {
    console.log(json[key]);
}
```